# Error establishing a database connection problem in xampp saver

Tags: database

Im beginner for the **word press** development, Im try to install my local host to word press but i had following problem, can you please help me to fix this

My WP-CONFIG

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('lanka', 'database_name_here');

/** MySQL database username */
define('root', 'username_here');

/** MySQL database password */
define('', 'password_here');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('localhost', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

**Error establishing a database connection**

This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at DB_HOST. This could mean your host’s database server is down.

Are you sure you have the correct username and password?
Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname?
Are you sure that the database server is running?
If you’re unsure what these terms mean you should probably contact your host. If you still need help you can always visit the WordPress Support Forums.

Comment: You have fill out it wrong, on the left side of the function `define()` is the constant, not the value, like `define('DB_NAME', 'lanka');`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WP-CONFIG file should be like below-

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name_here');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'username_here');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

You have filled values in wrong side.